# How to get a Page from a class in asp website

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, web-services, asp.net-ajax

sorry for my bad English.
I have a `Default.aspx` page in my project containing a textbox and a button. So when the client clicks on the button, the browser calls a method that is in my web service `WebService.asmx.cs` whit the `textbox.Text` as parameter.
`(e.g NameSpace.WebService.Say("Hi"); in js)`
But I need to report the results `("Hi")` to my Default page for showing them in an `UpdatePanel` and I don't know how to get the page.
I tried `(Default)HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler` but it was `null`.
Is there any other way to get that page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access the Page object while calling a static(webmethod) method. Static methods cant access instance of the Class it is part of.

Options you have are:
 1. Save the value in Session. (HttpContext.Current.Session should be accessible) and show it on the next page load, after accessing it from session. This is a roundabout way and you will have to decorate the webmethod with this attribute:`[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]`
 2. Instead of using webservice, just update the label in Client side itself using Javascript.

Comment: As you said, there is no way to do that. So I'm using AJAX now and it's awesome.